# How to select an attribute which name equal to a variable value?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

The following SQL Server (Version 2008) code

```
declare @x xml = '
<PKs>
  <Column Name="a" />
  <Column Name="b" />
</PKs>
<Selected>
  <row a="444010" b="2" />
  <row a="444012" b="3" />
  <row a="444003" b="2" />
  <row a="444009" b="4" />
  <row a="444002" b="3" />
  <row a="444005" b="1" />
</Selected>'

declare @s nvarchar(max) = @x.query('
for $r in /Selected/row 
return <s>({
    for $k in /PKs/Column 
    return <s>{data($k/@Name)} = {data($r[.=$k/@Name])} and </s>}1=1) or
    </s>').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
print @s
```

returns

```
(a =  and b =  and 1=1) or
    (a =  and b =  and 1=1) or
    (a =  and b =  and 1=1) or
    (a =  and b =  and 1=1) or
    (a =  and b =  and 1=1) or
    (a =  and b =  and 1=1) or
```

The expected result is

```
(a = 444010 and b = 2 and 1=1) or
    (a = 444012 and b = 3 and 1=1) or
    (a = 444003 and b = 2 and 1=1) or
    (a = 444009 and b = 4 and 1=1) or
    (a = 444002 and b = 3 and 1=1) or
    (a = 444005 and b = 1 and 1=1) or
```

The problem is in the line `return <s>{data($k/@Name)} = {data($r[.=$k/@Name])} and </s>}1=1) or`, I need to select the value of `$r/@($k/@Name)` (which has Syntax error) instead of `$r[.=$k/@Name]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically computing attribute names is not really idiomatic XQuery, but it can be done by enumerating all attributes using `@*` and then manually filtering the one you want by accessing its name using [`fn:local-name()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-local-name):

```
for $r in /Selected/row 
return <s>({
    for $k in /PKs/Column
    let $col := $r/@*[local-name()=$k/@Name]
    return <s>{data($k/@Name)} = {data($col)} and </s>}1=1) or
    </s>
```